# To get a prompt which indicates Git-branch in Zsh

Tags: git, zsh, prompt

I run the following codes separately as my prompt unsuccessfully in .zshrc. This suggests me that apparently I do not have a program called __git_ps1. It is not in MacPorts.

### #1

```
PROMPT="$(__git_ps1 " \[\033[1;32m\] (%s)\[\033[0m\]")\$"$
```

### #2

```
PROMPT="$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\$"$
```

### [#3](http://pastie.org/325104)

```
# Get the name of the branch we are on
git_prompt_info() {
  branch_prompt=$(__git_ps1)
  if [ -n "$branch_prompt" ]; then
    status_icon=$(git_status)
    echo $branch_prompt $status_icon
  fi
}

# Show character if changes are pending
git_status() {
  if current_git_status=$(git status | grep 'added to commit' 2> /dev/null); then
    echo "☠"
  fi
}
autoload -U colors
colors
setopt prompt_subst
PROMPT='
%~%{$fg_bold[black]%}$(git_prompt_info)
→ %{$reset_color%}'
```

**How can you get a prompt which shows the name of a Git-branch?**

Comment: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Version-Control-Information

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`__git_ps1` is from git-completion.bash. In zsh you probably have to provide your own function to determine the current directories git branch. There are quite a few [blog posts](http://www.jukie.net/%7Ebart/blog/zsh-git-prompt) about a [git prompt](http://nullcreations.net/entries/general/zsh-prompt-to-show-git-branch) for zsh.

You just need:

- a function to provide the branch name
- enable prompt (command) substitution
- add the function to your prompt

For example

```sh
git_prompt() {
 ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | cut -d'/' -f3)
 echo $ref
}
setopt prompt_subst
PS1=$(git_prompt)%#
autoload -U promptinit
promptinit
```

**Update: use the zsh vcs_info module instead of git_prompt()**

```sh
setopt prompt_subst
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' actionformats \
    '%F{5}(%f%s%F{5})%F{3}-%F{5}[%F{2}%b%F{3}|%F{1}%a%F{5}]%f '
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats       \
    '%F{5}(%f%s%F{5})%F{3}-%F{5}[%F{2}%b%F{5}]%f '
zstyle ':vcs_info:(sv[nk]|bzr):*' branchformat '%b%F{1}:%F{3}%r'

zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git cvs svn

# or use pre_cmd, see man zshcontrib
vcs_info_wrapper() {
  vcs_info
  if [ -n "$vcs_info_msg_0_" ]; then
    echo "%{$fg[grey]%}${vcs_info_msg_0_}%{$reset_color%}$del"
  fi
}
RPROMPT=$'$(vcs_info_wrapper)'
```

Comment: git_prompt is wrong, if you have a branch with / it does not work. Use `cut -d'/' -f3-` instead.

Comment: Thanks!, this works. Can you please explain what those cryptic zstyle commands do?

Comment: @balki The `%F{n}` enable [ANSI color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) `n` for foreground, and `%f` disables foreground color.  E.g., the `formats` format `%F{5}(%f%s%F{5})%F{3}-%F{5}[%F{2}%b%F{3}]%f ` becomes `(%s)-[%b]` if you ignore the colors. The `%s` gets replaced by the vc system (e.g. git) and the `%b` gets replaced by the current branch.

Comment: @balki The `(sv[nk]|bzr)` subpattern on the `branchformat` restricts it to `svn`, `svk`, and `bzr`.  It means that those systems should use `branch:revision` instead of the default `branch`.  Because of the `enable` line, `bzr` is not supported, so this `bzr` restriction is "dead code".  The first three lines are copied verbatim from the [ZSH docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Version-Control-Information), but the last line was added by someone else, which probably explains the dead code.

Comment: @balki The `actionformats` becomes `(%s)-[%b|%a]` ignoring colors. This format is used during special actions, with `%a` describing the action.  This is the most useful feature IMHO: e.g. for git it tells when you are in the middle of a rebase (which I often forget about while trying to resolve merge conflicts).

Comment: I've been using this for a long time, and it always worked well. Now however, after updating to zsh 5.0.7 and git 1.8.4, I get "fatal: Not a git repository" whenever going into a directory that is not a git repo. Any suggestions? (I see many discussions on detecting whether or not we're in a git repo, but I don't want to exit early if not, I also have svn repos... vcs_info was great at encapsulating all that...)

Comment: Ah, found a solution: replacing the call to vcs_info with vcs_info 2>/dev/null

Comment: link for `git prompt` seems dead :(

Comment: In the first simple solution, also use `cut -d'/' -f3-`, it will make sure to include the full name of the branch, if the branch name is like `feature/xyz`

Answer (score 71):

A lot of these solutions seemed slow for me when mashing the return key, so here's an option that is basic and speedy:

```sh
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='%9c%{%F{green}%}$(parse_git_branch)%{%F{none}%} $ '
```

You'll get a prompt that looks like this:
`~/dev/project (feature-branch) $`

Comment: `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2> /dev/null` will get you an answer that requires less parsing.

Comment: Where to add this code?

Comment: @Manish in your ~/.zshrc file

Comment: Please note that the PROMPT must be in single quotes for the command to be re-run whenever changing directories

Answer (score 52):

Here is an extended git prompt for zsh: [zsh-git-prompt](https://github.com/zsh-git-prompt/zsh-git-prompt).

[image]

Comment: Love it! Perfect. Very nice work, and now a submodule in my own dotfiles repo. :)

Comment: How does your approach compare to vcs_info? It seems that your script is reinventing the wheel? (Didn't stop me from using it though, I was unaware of vcs_info)

Comment: having trouble during sourcing: " unrecognized modifier `A'". zsh 4.2.6 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu). Is it a known issue?

Comment: Repository no longer maintained - seems like some guys took over here: https://github.com/zsh-git-prompt/zsh-git-prompt editing answer to link to it

Comment: Couldn't make it run neither with the repo I mention above. Found out ohmyzsh does it nicely, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63919265/1920149

Answer (score 41):

ko-dos's answer is great, but I prefer a slightly more git aware prompt than the one he uses. Specifically, I like staged, unstaged, and untracked file notifications in the prompt itself. Using his answer and the [zsh vcs_info examples,](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Misc/vcs_info-examples) I came up with the following:

```
setopt prompt_subst
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' stagedstr 'M' 
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' unstagedstr 'M' 
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' check-for-changes true
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' actionformats '%F{5}[%F{2}%b%F{3}|%F{1}%a%F{5}]%f '
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats \
  '%F{5}[%F{2}%b%F{5}] %F{2}%c%F{3}%u%f'
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*+set-message:*' hooks git-untracked
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git 
+vi-git-untracked() {
  if [[ $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> /dev/null) == 'true' ]] && \
  [[ $(git ls-files --other --directory --exclude-standard | sed q | wc -l | tr -d ' ') == 1 ]] ; then
  hook_com[unstaged]+='%F{1}??%f'
fi
}


precmd () { vcs_info }
PROMPT='%F{5}[%F{2}%n%F{5}] %F{3}%3~ ${vcs_info_msg_0_} %f%# '
```

This creates a prompt that mimics the colorized output of `git status -s` (which can be configured in your `.gitconfig` file). A picture is perhaps most helpful here:

[image: prompt]

Compared with `git status -s`:

[image]

If you don't like colorized output, or would prefer some other character or prompt construction, just change the `stagedstr`, `unstagedstr`, and `hook_com[unstaged]` values in the above code.

Comment: This is a great git-specific use of `vcs_info`. One thing though: `git status` is *slow*. I used `git ls-files --other --directory --exclude-standard | sed q | wc -l | tr -d ' '` instead, and it's much faster.

Comment: Nice modification. Updated accordingly.

Comment: The `--directory` flag might not actually be necessary. I found that it was annoying because git usually ignores empty directories.

Comment: Had the same problem (i.e. empty directories ignored by git caused `??` to appear in the prompt). Fixed by adding `--no-empty-directory` flag to the `git ls-files` command.

Answer (score 10):

I just redid mine since we have long branch names at work. This one will truncate with an ellipsis if it's more than 35 characters.

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"
    pattern="On branch ([^[:space:]]*)"
    if [[ ! ${git_status} =~ "(working (tree|directory) clean)" ]]; then
        state="*"
    fi
    if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${pattern} ]]; then
      branch=${match[1]}
      branch_cut=${branch:0:35}
      if (( ${#branch} > ${#branch_cut} )); then
          echo "(${branch_cut}…${state})"
      else
          echo "(${branch}${state})"
      fi
    fi
}

setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='%{%F{blue}%}%9c%{%F{none}%}$(parse_git_branch)$'
```

(I'm embarrassed at how proud I am of this.)

Comment: Please note that the PROMPT must be in single quotes for the command to be re-run whenever changing directories

Comment: Like it is @WestonGanger or you're suggesting something else?

Answer (score 9):

This already has a many great answers, and seems like the authoritative Question for readers who don't want to use more than the `zsh` config and `git`.

However, I found myself wanting simply

```
working-directory (git-branch-color-if-uncommitted) %          24h-timestamp
```

```sh
git_branch_test_color() {
  local ref=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2> /dev/null)
  if [ -n "${ref}" ]; then
    if [ -n "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then
      local gitstatuscolor='%F{red}'
    else
      local gitstatuscolor='%F{green}'
    fi
    echo "${gitstatuscolor} (${ref})"
  else
    echo ""
  fi
}
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='%9c$(git_branch_test_color)%F{none} %# '

# add 24h time the right side
RPROMPT='%D{%k:%M:%S}'
```

[image: prompt coloration example]

This works by

- allowing inclusion of a function (`$()`) by setting `PROMPT_SUBST` (thanks to [**Phil's** 2017 answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178134/4541045))
- declaring a function `git_branch_test_color` to call `git` for the branch ref ..and by whether this succeeds (tests for stdout) if the current directory is a git repository
  (thanks to a few comments for `symbolic-ref` arg!)

  - if not a git repo, only echo an empty string `""`
- if the initial call did succeed (does have collected stdout), the current directory *is a git directory* and
  `git status --porcelain` is used to determine if any files have been changed or are new/deleted

  - green coloration prefix for unchanged
  - red coloration prefix for changes (whatever they may be)

---

Note that all such prompts can be slow on mounted directories (especially via `sshfs`). If this is experienced, I recommend special-casing those directories if at all possible (perhaps create a new shell function to check if cd is in your collection) or always mount in the same path and ignore it ([example with `vcs_info`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure/issues/189#issuecomment-173844254))

Answer (score 5):

If all your prompt looks fine but it does not work, e.g:

```
function git_branch(){                                                                                                                 
    ref=$(git symbolic-ref --short --quiet HEAD 2>/dev/null)        
    if [ -n "${ref}" ]; then                                                    
        echo "(""$ref"")"                                                       
    fi                                                                          
}                                                                               
                                                                                
setopt PROMPT_SUBST                                                             

PROMPT="%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%m:%{$fg[yellow]%}%1~%{$reset_color%} %{%F{green}%}$(git_branch)%{%F{none}%}$ "
```

The PROMPT must set to a string quoted using single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
PROMPT='%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%m:%{$fg[yellow]%}%1~%{$reset_color%} %{%F{green}%}$(git_branch)%{%F{none}%}$ '
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this tip about single quotes. My desire to use double quotes bit me here.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested in a maintained ready-made solution, install https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh - it has a git plugin turned on by default. I was looking for sth like this - no-brainer pre-created configuration, works nice.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the links!

I made the following prompt based on them

```
     # get the name of the branch we are on
     git_prompt_info() { 
         git branch | awk '/^\*/ { print $2 }'
     }
     get_git_dirty() { 
       git diff --quiet || echo '*'
     }

     autoload -U colors
     colors     
     setopt prompt_subst

     PROMPT='%{$fg[blue]%}%c %{$fg_bold[red]%}$(git_prompt_info)$(get_git_dirty)%{$fg[blue]%} $ %{$reset_color%}'                                           

     RPROMPT='%{$fg[green]%}%1(j.%j.)'
```

Please, suggest any improvements.

Comment: Do not use git-branch. It is porcelain, meant for UI, not for scripting. Use git-symbolic-ref and BR=${BR#refs/heads/}

Comment: @Jakub: Thank you for pointing that out! --- I just observed that git-branch causes bugs with non-git directories.

Comment: @Jakub Narębski: You can also do `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`, which will remove the "refs/heads/" business for you.